# Errors with assigment and no errors with replacement rule, why?

Tags: warning-messages, series-expansion, assignment

So I have an expression, let's call it f11 which is a function of t of this form `f11= a1*t^(-4)+ a3*t^(-3)+...` and so on up until a finite positive power of t. In the expression there are some coefficient of the powers of t, for example `\[Sigma]1`. Now if I write something like this:

```
f11= bla bla
\[Sigma]1 = 0;
Series[f11, {t, 0, -2}]
```

these 3 errors appear

- Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0^2 encountered.
- Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
- Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity encountered.

If I instead write

```
f11= bla bla
Series[f11, {t, 0, -2}] /. \[Sigma]1 -> 0
```

no error occours and everything is fine, why is that so?

I'd prefer to set the variable `\[Sigma]1` to 0 once and for all not apply the rule `/. \[Sigma]1 -> 0` everytime so having to apply the rule is kind of a nuisance

EDIT: Also I want to point out that I have other parameters inside `f11` like `\[Sigma]2` or `a1` and so on and when I assign them to 0 they cause no problem whatsoever, but thye enter inside `f11` more or less in the same way `\[Sigma]1` does. In fact in the rest of the notebook, I assign `\[Sigma]2=0` and then go on writing the series expansion of `f11` but I always have to keep the rule `/. \[Sigma]1 -> 0`

EDIT 2: To make it clearer I will post here the essentials of my notebook:

```
a = A*(t + a2*t^2 + a3*t^3 + a4*t^4 + O[t]^5);
H = (\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]a\))/a;
\[Sigma] = \[Sigma]i*(1 + \[Sigma]1*t + \[Sigma]2*t^2 + \[Sigma]3*
  t^3 + \[Sigma]4*t^4 + O[t]^5);
f1 = H^2 == 
a^2*(\[Rho]r0/a^4(*+(\[Rho]m0/a^3)*)+ V)/(
 3*\[Gamma]*\[Sigma]^2) + (\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\[Sigma]\))^2/(
6*\[Gamma]*\[Sigma]^2) - 2*H*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\[Sigma]\)/\[Sigma] + (\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\[Sigma]\))^3/(
 3*\[Gamma]*a^2*\[Sigma]^2)*(6*g*H - dg*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\[Sigma]\));
f11 = Collect[Expand[f1], t];
```

At this point I do the commands mentioned above and I have the problem mentioned above. I do it in this way cause f11 is a bit of a long expression and I want to isolate the term order by order and see them, without necessarly know them in advance. For clarity I will also post the screenshots from my notebook which would be easier to read with respect to the code written in that way

Some quantities that enter f11:

[image: Some quantities that enter f11]

Definition of `f11` and errors with assignment `[Sigma]1 = 0`:
[image: Definition of f11 and errors]

Definition of `f11` and no errors with rule `/.[Sigma]1->0]`:
[image: Definition of f11 and no errors]

Complete expression of `f11`:

[image: Complete expression of f11]

Comment: If f11 is already a power series, why do you say Series[f11, {t, 0, -2}] . Further, the order of a power series can not be a negative number.

Comment: @DanielHuber you are right, I simply have a function of t. For your first question, I write Series[f11, {t, 0, -2}] to show me only the terms up to the order -2

Comment: @DanielHuber I edited the question, is it more clear now?

Comment: You should post the term containing x1. Otherwise it is hard to tell what is going on.Your original expression looks already like a (by the way it is called Laurent series, not power series because of the negative powers) Laurent series. Why do you need "Series?"

Comment: @DanielHuber Hi I edited the question, I hope it's clearer now. I use series to see the terms inside f11 only up to a certain order, is there another way to do this? I posted the entire screenshot of the form of f11, the point is that I don't want to see that form or look for where the terms like sigma1 or sigma2 comes up, I just want to see them order by order

Comment: The problem is not with "Series", but with "f11". There you have terms with 1/\[Sigma]1, therefore setting \[Sigma]1 =0 will give an error in f11. Convince yourself by: f11 /. \[Sigma]1 ->0

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you, I somehow failed to see those terms even though I was explicitly looking for them until you told me they were present. They appear usually as ((sigma1)^2)/(sigma1). Is your advice to use Simplify in order to get rid of those terms and avoid having sigma1 at the denominators? Are there other problems related to me setting sigma1=0 or if I have simplified f11 earlier I should not worry about it in general?

Comment: It is always a good idea to use "Simplify" after construction of a complicated expression. You just saw an example what can happen if you don't. In addition, MMA may proceed much faster if it can deal with simpler expressions.Finally, it is also easier for the human animal to see what is going on.